# Securing APIs using basic authentication hander in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using an API that works as a gateway between my back-end service and external clients. i'm trying to secure the access to my API with basic authentication using user/password base encoding. After following some guides, i added the handler section in my API in order to manage the auth module.

I tried this section :

```html
<handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.rest.BasicAuthHandler"/>
    </handlers>
```

The Auth handler is working good for me but only with admin/admin credentials even if i change the password of the user admin.
How can i add a user and let him consume my API with specefic credentials?

Comment: try **org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a user using the WSO2 EI Management console following the below steps.

1. Click **Configure** in the menu tab on the left side and click **Add** under **Users and Roles**.
2. Select **Add new user**
3. Enter Username and Password and click **Next**
4. Select Roles of the User and click **Finish** (I selected admin privileges)

Then I deployed following API as mentioned in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u8RS.png)

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="StockQuoteAPI" 

context="/stockquote">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/view/{symbol}">
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
                  <m0:request>
                     <m0:symbol>$1</m0:symbol>
                  </m0:request>
               </m0:getQuote>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.symbol')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:getQuote"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
   <handlers>
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</api>
```

Then I could send the request using postman with the new username/password.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u8RS.png) https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+an+API#ApplyingSecuritytoanAPI-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. i tried to change "org.wso2.rest.BasicAuthHandler by "org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler" in my api and redeployed it. I got this error

```html
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v60
```

It seems that i need the .jar file in order to load it but i cannot find it. Can you please provide a link to download please?

Comment: Follow this [doc]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+an+API#ApplyingSecuritytoanAPI-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler

Comment: Whats the product version you are using?

Comment: i'm using 6.3.0 m8 as ESB

Comment: Check the doc shared. It should work. It worked for me EI 6.5.0

Comment: I followed the doc and the handler does not work for me :(

Comment: you should check the doc for the version you are using and I recommend you to upgrade to the latest version 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to 6.5.0 version of the ESB and it worked. thanks !